# How to access function from a variable configuration in angular 10

Tags: angular

I have a variable declaration as below

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  // constructor() { }
  config = {
    // replace this key with yours
    publicKey: "test_public_key_dc74e0fd57cb46cd93832aee0a390234",
    productIdentity: "1234567890",
    productName: "Drogon",
    productUrl: "http://gameofthrones.com/buy/Dragons",
    eventHandler: {
      onSuccess(payload) {
        // hit merchant api for initiating verfication
        console.log(payload);
        this.handleSuccessResponse(payload);
      },
      // onError handler is optional
      onError(error) {
        // handle errors
        console.log(error);
      },
      onClose() {
        console.log("widget is closing");
      }
    }
  };
  checkout = new KhaltiCheckout(this.config);

  ngOnInit() {}
  khaltiCheckout() {
    this.checkout.show({ amount: 1000 });
  }
  handleSuccessResponse(payload) {
    console.log(payload);
  }

  handleErrorResponse(payload) {
    console.log(payload);
  }
}
```

Here, this.generateAlphaNumericValue(10) has been called successfully but the function this.handleSuccessResponse(payload) throws error as undefined function.
How can I call this.handleSuccessResponse(payload) on success event.

Comment: Can I see a code, where and how exactly you are calling `onSuccess` function?

Comment: Directly pass the function refrerence i.e. `onSuccess = this.handleSuccessResponse"` or   Use arror function i.e. `onSuccess  => (payload) > {        this.handleSuccessResponse(payload);   },`

Comment: @PankajParkar I have updated the code. Can you check it.

Comment: @Satpal is right, you can use Arrow function to hold the component class context inside `onSuccess` function.

Comment: @Satpal onSuccess is a callback function. I can't either assign or use arrow function. I have to call a function from within onSuccess function .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.successR(payload);` is not in the scope of config scope is lost because of the inner function, so change it like this,

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
    // Change
    var self = this;
    config = {
        // replace this key with yours
        publicKey: "test_public_key_dc74e0fd57cb46cd93832aee0a390234",
        productIdentity: "1234567890",
        productName: "Drogon",
        productUrl: "http://gameofthrones.com/buy/Dragons",
        eventHandler: {
          onSuccess(payload) {
            // Change
            self.successR(payload);
          },
          // onError handler is optional
          onError(error) {
            // handle errors
            console.log(error);
          },
          onClose() {
            console.log("widget is closing");
          }
        }
      };
      checkout = new KhaltiCheckout(this.config);
   }
}
```